# How to generate this format number YYYYMM0001?

Tags: php

I need to generate a set of number consist of Current Year, Current Month, and Incremental 4 digit with zero leading. with conditions:

1. The last 4 digit number is increment from the last record on database.

example:

```
 2020080023 -> last database record
 2020080024 -> so this is will be the next record
```

2. on beginning of month the last 4 digit reset to 0001.

example:

```
 2020080023 -> last database record on end of month
 2020090001 -> so this is will be the next record
```

this is what i have so far:

```
$currentYear = date('Y');
$currentMonth = date('m');
$last4Digits = '0001';
$formatedNumber = $currentYear.$currentMonth.$last4Digits;
```

Question how to increment the last 4 digit from last record and how to reset to 0001 on beginning of month?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is how to increment the last 4 digit from last record and how to reset to 0001 on begining of month ? thanks for asking

Comment: While this can be eased with `printf()` / `sprintf()`, your current code renders `2020080001` as of today. Isn't it correct?

Comment: Convert value to int, increment, pad with zeros if required.

Comment: Then, check if current day is number one of current month: `date('j') === 1`; if yes reset that counter to `0001`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution requires the last formatted ID and a little logic. If the last ID is in the current month, it only needs to be increased by 1. If this is not the case, the new month starts at 1.

```
function getId($lastId){
  $curYm = (int)date('Ym');
  $lastYm = (int)($lastId/10000);
  if($lastYm == $curYm) return ++$lastId;
  return $curYm * 10000 + 1;
}
```

examples:

```
$id = 2020080007;
$nextId = getId($id); //int(2020080008)

$id = 2020070127;
$nextId = getId($id); // int(2020080001)
```

Answer (score 0):

get the last records month and check if $currentMonth and lastrecords month are same if same just increment current $last4Digits otherwise set $last4Digits = '0001'

```
$currentYear = date('Y');
$currentMonth = date('m');

// last record from db
$db_last4Digits = //data from db;
$db_last4Digits_month = substr($db_last4Digits, 4, 2);
$db_last4Digits_month = substr($db_last4Digits, 6);


if($db_last4Digits_month == $currentMonth){
$last4Digits = '0001'; // set to 0001 if current month is not equal to last month
}else{
$last4Digits = substr($db_last4Digits, -4, 4); //get last 4 numbers
$last4Digits += $last4Digits ;
}


$formatedNumber = $currentYear.$currentMonth.$last4Digits;
```